# Can't display ListView from SQLite

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-sqlite

Can't display ListView from SQLite.
How do I solve this problem?

```
public class MainActivitySleman extends AppCompatActivity {
TukangDB dbcenter;
protected Cursor cursor;
String [] daftar;
ListView list;
public static MainActivitySleman sleman;
private String cariTukang;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity_sleman);

    dbcenter = new TukangDB(this);
    sleman = this;
    RefreshList();
}

public void  RefreshList(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = dbcenter.getReadableDatabase();
    cursor = db.rawQuery("select no from tucall", null);
    daftar = new String[cursor.getCount()];
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount() ; i++) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        daftar[i] = cursor.getString(0).toString();
    }
    list = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewSleman);
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter(this,     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, daftar));
    list.setSelected(true);
    list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            final String selection = daftar[position];
            Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Detail.class);
            i.putExtra("no", selection);
            startActivity(i);
        }
    }) ;
    ((ArrayAdapter) list.getAdapter()).notifyDataSetChanged();
}
}
```

This is the code in my MainACtivity.
And this is the result from that code in my smartphone:

[image: Screenshot from my smartphone]

I cannot display the data from SQLite.
I already saved the data by using SQL commands.

What should I do?

Comment: Post the code of the TukangDB class please

Comment: Log the contents of cursor.getString(0).toString() and verify if data is there or not

Answer (score 0):

Since you instantiate `TukangDB` just before calling `RefreshList()`, the only way you could have data in it if you populate it in it's constructor.

I assume you have not done that, so your DB is empty when you're trying to fetch data from it.

Posting the code of `TukangDB` class would let us see what the problem is for sure.

Answer (score 0):

this is my TukangDB class

```
public class TukangDB extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "tucall.db";

public TukangDB(Context context) {
    super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    String sql = "create table tucall(no integer primary key, nama text null, alamat text null, no_hp text null, keahlian text null, tarif integer, wilayah text null)";
    Log.d("Data", "onCreate: "+sql);
    db.execSQL(sql);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
```

}

Answer (score -1):

Can you post your ArrayAdapter class?
Is your daftar object empty or not?
I suggest you to use ArrayList instead String[].

Comment: how to check my ArrayAdapter class because i can't check my daftar object empty or not.
why use ArrayList? is using ArrayAdapter or cursor can't be implement?

Comment: You can check your daftar object if you use Debug or add a Log. You can implement cursor, I suggest you ArrayList because is changeable, unlike String[]. But you can use what you want. Where you put some data in your TukangDB??

Comment: i can't see the data that i already input like use sql developer, so i can check the data. but in the activity register showing succes save data.